# Extremely slow execution of .asmx web service code

Tags: performance, iis-7, mysql-connector

I know this is similar to a couple of other questions, but none of the answers have helped me.  I have a .asmx web service running on Windows 2008, IIS 7, and connects with MySql over MySql Connector Net.   The web service takes in a string, converts it to XML with Xmldocument... then loops through the child nodes and finally updates the database.  On a console app on the same machine it will run in 2-3 seconds.  In the .asmx web service it takes 2-3 minutes.  I've made sure that the data is arriving immediately in the code... it actually just takes forever to run.  I'm hoping someone can point me towards some settings in the app pool or in IIS to give it more resources.  This is a 1.7 GB ram machine, I don't think resources should be an issue. This is being called by Python program, but I've called it from a couple of different places and still its so slow. Please spare the lecture on WCF as some of us don't have complete control over what we develop anyway.  Any help to point me in the right direction would be great!

Answer (score 0):

Either enable [Tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb885203.aspx) or use a [profiler](http://www.eqatec.com/tools/profiler/) to find what is taking so long.

On a few hunches, is it the same code base between the console and ASMX (e.g. is this code in a separate class and called from both, or copy and pasted?)? And how big is the XML blob being sent to the server? Building the DOM takes time, if you're just reading through it once and generating inserts, look at using [XmlReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.aspx) instead.

Hopefully one of these will get you going in the right direction.